# Reset column with numeric value that represents the order when destroying a row

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a table of users that has a column called `order` that represents the order in they will be elected.

So, for example, the table might look like:

```
| id  | name   | order | 
|-----|--------|-------|
| 1   | John   |  2    |
| 2   | Mike   |  0    |
| 3   | Lisa   |  1    |
```

So, say that now Lisa gets destroyed, I would like that in the same transaction that I destroy Lisa, I am able to update the table so the order is still consistent, so the expected result would be:

```
| id  | name   | order | 
|-----|--------|-------|
| 1   | John   |  1    |
| 2   | Mike   |  0    |
```

Or, if Mike were the one to be deleted, the expected result would be:

```
| id  | name   | order | 
|-----|--------|-------|
| 1   | John   |  1    |
| 3   | Lisa   |  0    |
```

How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just deleting one row, one option uses a cte and the `returning` clause to then trigger an `update`

```
with del as (
    delete from mytable where name = 'Lisa'
    returning ord
)
update mytable 
set ord = ord - 1
from del d
where mytable.ord > d.ord
```

As a more general approach, I would really recommend trying to renumber the whole table after every delete. This is inefficient, and can get tedious for multi-rows delete.

Instead, you could build a view on top of the table:

```
create view myview as
select id, name, row_number() over(order by ord) ord
from mytable
```